# Difference between slash operator and comma separator in pathlib Path

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I [read](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators) that in `pathlib` we can create a child path by using `/` between two paths, where a comma would also work. However, I can't find out if there is a difference between the two cases. In the following example, the output is the same:

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('/hello', 'world')
s = Path(p, 'how', 'are', 'you')
ns = Path(p / 'how', 'are', 'you')

print(s)
print(ns)
```

But considering that `pathlib` is heavily object-oriented, I guess there might be something different behind the scenes. Is there a difference between using `/` in Path in contrast with a comma?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The whole point of using the `/` operator between `pathlib.Path` objects or a `Path` object with a `str` object is so you can *avoid* wrapping everything in calls to `Path`.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path('/hello', 'world')
>>> p / 'how'
PosixPath('/hello/world/how')
>>> p / 'how' / 'are' / 'you'
PosixPath('/hello/world/how/are/you')
```

The distinction isn't between using "a comma" and a `/`, it's between using `/` and the constructor, `Path`.

I suppose, `/` is supposed to be similar to `joinpath`:

```
>>> p.joinpath('how','are','you')
PosixPath('/hello/world/how/are/you')
```

But somewhere under the hood you are creating a new `Path` instance, so `Path` is called anyway.

Note, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pure-paths):

> When several absolute paths are given, the last is taken as an anchor
>   (mimicking os.path.join()’s behaviour):

So they both have this behavior as well:

```
>>> '/etc' / p / '/usr'
PosixPath('/usr')
>>> Path('/etc', p, '/usr')
PosixPath('/usr')
```